# Gridview with listview inside android

Tags: android

I have a view in my app where I have to display multiple listviews alongside each other, each containing data for a different user. So what I have done so far is I have a gridview with columns, and within each column I populate the gridview cell with a listview. This works fine, however, it displays the same listview twice, instead of displaying different listviews for each column. The strange thing is that if I replace the list view with a normal label, it displays the data from different users.

Main Activity where I set the gridview adapter:

```
gridview.setNumColumns(10);
                gridview.setHorizontalSpacing(205);
                gridview.setStretchMode(0);
                gridview.setAdapter(new Adapter_Labels_GridView_Calendar_dayview(mContext, Session_CurrentSession.current_CALENDAR));
```

This is the adapter for the gridview... just the getview section. (You will see that is where I set the adapter for the listviews that displays the same listview and not different ones)

```
 public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {

  ListView list;

  if (convertView == null)
  {  
       // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes  
       list = new ListView(mContext);
       list.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 500));
       list.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
   }  
  else
  {  
       list = (ListView) convertView;  
  }  


  list.setAdapter(new Adapter_ListView_GridView_Calendar(mContext, dagtyeVanhaarkappers.get(position), gebookdeurUser.get(position), tekening.get(position)));
  list.setCacheColorHint(0);

  list.setId(position);

  list.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {   
                // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });

  return list;
 }
```

}

Thanks in Advance

EDIT:

Here is the gridview on touch event in the main activity:

```
  gridview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
     {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
               if(isDayView && created)
               {
                   int numchilds = gridview.getChildCount();
                   for(int i = 0; i < numchilds; i++)
                   {
                       gridview.getChildAt(i).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                   }
               }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

EDIT: getview of Adapter_ListView_GridView_Calendar

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_bookingslist, parent , false);

            ImageView booking_image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.booking_image);
    TextView textBookingTime = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.booking_time);
    TextView textBookingUser = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.booking_byuser);

            booking_image.setImageDrawable(drawables.get(position));
            textBookingTime.setText(daytimes.get(position));
            textBookingUser.setText(bookedbyuser.get(position));


    return rowView;
}
```

**ANSWER FINALLY:**

I've found the problem... I thought the problem was with the adapter because of my weird view (Listview inside gridview)... However, I was not making new instances of the data when reading them into an arraylist using a for loop, so the string had the same reference in memory. Thus, when modyfying either one, I was actually modyfying the same instance of that object. Damn, can't beleive I did not see such a simple little thing. Thank You for all the help.

Comment: Post the comment of your Adapter_ListView_GridView_Calendar getView() class. You say the list is repeated that means the adapter in the listview is setting the same data somewhere. You ened to check that properly!

Comment: Do you want the entire class ?

Comment: I want the code of getView() of Adapter_ListView_GridView_Calendar if you can provide?

Comment: sure thing, I'll edit it in the original post.

Comment: Ok, that does not help anything. Could you try one thing? Put a debug point in the Contructor of  Adapter_ListView_GridView_Calendar and check if you are getting the same data there?

Comment: Another thing I have noticed: It does not actually display the same users details twice, it displays both users details in the same listview instead of seperate listviews. Right now, user 1 has a booking from 12:00 to 12:45 and user 2 has a booking from 06:00 to 07:00. It displays all the bookings on the same listview instead of user 1's bookings in listview 1 and user 2's bookings in listview 2. However, I have also double checked the input and it seems fine.

Comment: I think I have found the problem... Still debuggin, but it seems to be an input error, the way and the amount of data I enter into the listviews is very complex, I might have slipped up somewhere there.

Comment: @Antrromet , thank you for your help. Even though the problem lied somewhere else, you're idea of using the line breaks/debugging tools lead me to the cause of the problem. Thx

Comment: I am glad your problem was solved!

Comment: @Janpan I am working on similar kind of layout but in my case I am not able to populate data into listview from adapter what may be the reason for that?

Comment: could you pls post your code ? I am implementing similar functionality, but I am facing scrolling & item selection issues when the list items increase.

Answer (score 1):

```
final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mobile, parent, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.raw_mylist);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            // PARENT
    mListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.v("PARENT", "PARENT TOUCH");
            rowView.findViewById(R.id.raw_mylist).getParent()
                    .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return false;
        }
    });

            //your grid view as child
    listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.v("CHILD", "CHILD TOUCH");
            // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
            // child view
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

in getview method of your main adapter.

Comment: I do not have a listviewm in the xml layout, I create them in code dynamically. I already do what you proposed above.

Comment: but u didnt wrote gridview touch in ur getview method.

Comment: I did it in the main activity, I will edit in the main post to show.

Comment: It does exactly the same. Just note that the touch and scrolling works fine, the problem is that its displaying the same results twice.